# ODBCConnection Issue when Opening the connection

Tags: c#, service, odbc

I'm having some issues with a windows service that I have running. I've created a new test service that creates an ODBCConnection with a connection string that I have verified many times to be correct. Whenever I call the Open() method, I get the following error:

```
Error: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [08001] [Simba][SimbaEngine ODBC         Driver][DRM File Library]Invalid account name.
ERROR [IM006] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed
ERROR [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The driver doesn't support the version of ODBC    behavior that the application requested (see SQLSetEnvAttr).
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionHandle..ctor(OdbcConnection connection, OdbcConnectionString     constr, OdbcEnvironmentHandle environmentHandle)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionOpen..ctor(OdbcConnection outerConnection, OdbcConnectionString connectionOptions)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection   owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open()
```

I have the service running in 32 bit mode and the DSN is created in the 32-bit ODBC Administration tool. I am able to connect using an ODBC tester with the same connection string. I can also run the service through a command prompt and it will work perfectly. I have tried running the service as a user with the highest permissions, but that didn't help. Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this?

Here is the code that is running. I made it very basic to remove other factors:

```
string connectionString = "verified connection string";
string query = "random query I know works";
OdbcConnection c = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
 try
    {
        elog.WriteEntry("Opening odbc connection...", EventLogEntryType.Information);
        c.Open();
        elog.WriteEntry("Opened odbc connection...", EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }
    catch
    {
        c.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you try to connect to it?

Comment: Also what do you mean by ODBC tester? Did you set up the ODBC connection via `Control Panel -> Admin tools -> Data Sources (ODBC)` (you mean that?) and then set accordingly? And that test connection works ok?

Comment: Yes, I did all of that except I used 32-bit ODBC Administrator instead of Data Sources (ODBC) because the later is the 64-bit version